# rosmake skeleton_markers fails - how to install ready-to-use package?

Tags: ros-fuerte, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'd like to use skeleton_markers for displaying skeleton tracked by kinect in RViz on Ros fuerte, Ubuntu 12.04 x86. And I'm having problems.

I downloaded the skeleton_marker from svn, as suggested in ROS tutorial for skeleton-marker and I placed it in my ~/fuerte_wrkspc/sandbox (as suggested in tutorials for beginners). Now, when I try to

```
rosmake skeleton_markers
```

it gives an error :

```
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> skeleton_markers [ make ]                                                                                                                      
[ rosmake ] All 5 linesskeleton_markers: 0.1 sec ]                                                                                           [ 1 Active 34/35 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  CMake Error: The current CMakeCache.txt directory /home/da-na/fuerte_wrkspc/sandbox/skeleton_markers/build/CMakeCache.txt is different than the directory /home/da-na/fuerte_wrkspc/skeleton_markers/build where CMakeCache.txt was created. This may result in binaries being created in the wrong place. If you are not sure, reedit the CMakeCache.txt
  CMake Error: The source "/home/da-na/fuerte_wrkspc/sandbox/skeleton_markers/CMakeLists.txt" does not match the source "/home/da-na/fuerte_wrkspc/skeleton_markers/CMakeLists.txt" used to generate cache.  Re-run cmake with a different source directory.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package skeleton_markers written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/da-na/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130216-161404/skeleton_markers/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< skeleton_markers [FAIL] [ 0.13 seconds ]         rosmake skeleton_markers
```

I'm in the very begining of my adventure with ROS, so maybe I don't see some obvious steps that should be performed. I'll be gratefull for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55373/rosmake-skeleton_markers-fails---how-to-install-ready-to-use-package?/) by [da-na](https://answers.ros.org/users/4159/da-na/) on ROS Answers with karma: 306 on 2013-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try `make clean`, then compile it again.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0